# CefSharp possible to load html content?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I need to create a application which loads a html "template" file and parse them with current data values. So far no problemm but does anyone knows how to load the parsed html value into the cefsharp browser ?

I found some old topics here with an "loadHtml()" function. But this function isnt there anymore.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `using CefSharp;` statement to your code to access the [LoadHtml](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/100.0.x/html/Overload_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_LoadHtml.htm) extensions methods.

```cs
chromiumWebBrowser.LoadHtml(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string html = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Html Encoded in URL!</h1></body></html>";
var base64EncodedHtml = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html));
browser.Load("data:text/html;base64," + base64EncodedHtml);
```

From the project wiki on github: [Loading HTML/CSS/JavaScript/etc from disk/database/embedded resource/stream](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#loading-htmlcssjavascriptetc-from-diskdatabaseembedded-resourcestream)